# Filehelpers: parse fixed length file with different length of lines in

Tags: filehelpers, fixed-length-record, fixed-length-file

I've to parse a fixed length file containing multiple line but with different length.
Actually each line represent a different kind of object that would be insert in the database.
The file can be like this:

A10200JohnSmithUSA
B10000ContractSignedWithJohnSmith10200

Line 1..represent information regarding John Smith and Line 2 represents informations regarding contract signed by JohnSmith... All this come in the same file.

Can filehelpers library do that?

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes FileHelpers can handle multiple record types within the same file. It depends whether there is any hierarchical relation between the records. If not, you can use the `MultiRecordEngine`.

Check out the [MultiRecordEngine example](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_multirecords.html)

If your *contract* row needs to use information from the *John Smith* row, then you can use a `MasterDetailEngine`.

Check out the [MasterDetailEngine example](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_masterdetail.html)

Note however, the `MasterDetailEngine` only supports one level of nesting.